# Create a function to input data into the structure

Tags: c, recursion, struct

I created a structure like this:

```c
struct _symbol_ {
    int symbol_id;
    char *symbol_name;

    struct _symbol_ *next_symbol;
};

struct _symbol_ *symbol;
```

And next, I created a function to add data into structure:

```c
struct _symbol_ *new_symbol(int id, char *name, struct _symbol_ *next) {
    struct _symbol_ *s;
    s = (struct _symbol_ *)malloc(sizeof(struct _symbol_));

    if(s == NULL) {
        printf("unable to malloc _symbol_ structure\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    s -> symbol_id = id;

    if(name == NULL)
        s -> symbol_name = NULL;
    else {
        s -> symbol_name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
        strcpy(s -> symbol_name, name);
    }

    s -> next_symbol = NULL;
    return s;
}
```

I know this worked ! So this is the question.. **Data can be entered as follows**

```c
symbol = new_symbol(10, "a", NULL);
symbol -> next_symbol = new_symbol(10, "a", NULL);
symbol -> next_symbol -> next_symbol = new_symbol(10, "a", NULL);
```

**So i wrote another function to input data:**

```c
struct _symbol_ *add_symbol(int id, char *name) {
    if(symbol == NULL)
        return symbol = new_symbol(id, name, NULL);
    else
        return symbol -> next_symbol = new_symbol(id, name, NULL);
}
```

**but here only data** `symbol`, `symbol -> next_symbol` **are input. So how to write a function to input data correctly one by one?**

I mean this:

```
function INPUT_DATA(string name, structure pointer) {
  // Content
}

INPUT_DATA("1", symbol);
INPUT_DATA("2", symbol);
INPUT_DATA("3", symbol);

data 1 => symbol = "1"
data 2 => symbol -> next_symbol = "2"
data 3 => symbol -> next_symbol -> next_symbol = "3"
```

Comment: `INPUT_DATA()` should contain a loop that finds the end of the chain and puts the new symbol there.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. It worked 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
struct _symbol_ *add_symbol(int id, char *name) {
    int check = find_symbol(name, symbol);

    if(check == 1) {
        printf("symbol already available >>> %s\n", name);
        exit(1);
    }

    if(symbol == NULL)
        return symbol = new_symbol(id, name, NULL);
    else {
        // Add this code
        struct _symbol_ *current_node = symbol;

        while(current_node -> next_symbol != NULL) {
            current_node = current_node -> next_symbol;
        }

        return current_node -> next_symbol = new_symbol(id, name, NULL);
    }
}
```